# Another way of saying "easily deceived"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, vocabulary, pejorative-language

What's another way of saying *easily deceived*?

I want to have a better vocabulary. *Easily deceived* sounds a bit basic to me. Is there a better word for that phrase?

Comment: It depends on your intentions towards this type of person.  They may just be naïve or gullible as Eyguztav suggests or they may be "an easy mark"

Comment: [*Credulous*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/credulous).

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 9):

"Easily deceived" can be reworded as simply "gullible". If someone is "gullible" or "easily deceived", they are also "naive".

Comment: hi, and welcome to EL&U. This good answer would be made stronger with the definitions of your words added. Sources are appreciated, if you have the time, but as yours are easily found in a dictionary, I don't think a source is necessary here. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

A dupe is a man easily tricked

"A credulous man; a man easily tricked."

Answer (score 1):

There are also numerous informal or slang words for the person who is *gullible or easily deceived* including

> - patsy
> - mark
> - rube
> - sucker
> - dupe
> - chump
> - fall guy
> - gull
> - soft touch
> - mug
> - fool